# 60 second trigger versus 60 second delay aws-lambda/RDS error message?

Tags: javascript, sql, amazon-web-services, triggers, aws-lambda

We are attempting to create this lambda function in Node that seeds 30 days worth of information from an API, but we can only do it 1 day at a time due to the amount of information.  Our current attempts at doing this involve having a function that invokes a new instance of the lambda manually from within the lambda itself over and over, subtracting 1 day from the date each time it runs til HOW_MANY_DAYS_AGO > 0.  We upload the information to an RDS database, then run an sql statement that calculates the results, then posts them to a webpage.  If we run the lambda for 10 days or under, it works perfectly fine.  When we try to run for 30 days, we start getting this error around day 11 or 12 every time we run it.  We have tried setting a delay in different spots throughout the code because we assumed things were firing off too fast.

```
18:27:53
2017-05-09T18:27:53.505Z e720be2f-34e4-11e7-90ca-3f2ffa915b81 { StatusCode: 
200, FunctionError: 'Unhandled', Payload: '{"errorMessage":"RequestId: 
3243f8d3-34e5-11e7-b0a2-df429a0d6565 Process exited before completing 
request"}' }
2017-05-09T18:27:53.505Z e720be2f-34e4-11e7-90ca-3f2ffa915b81 { StatusCode: 
200,
FunctionError: 'Unhandled',
Payload: '{"errorMessage":"RequestId: 3243f8d3-34e5-11e7-b0a2-df429a0d6565 
Process exited before completing request"}' }
```

We also occasionally get a lambda error message in cloudwatch in the area where we pull back information from the API, which says the data variable is undefined, which also happens when it reaches the 11th or 12 day of information, but works when it is still under 10. That also made us think we are overloading the API we are using.

From my understanding, the payload from the error above is what we pass into the lambda in the event.variable.  We get this error on about day 11-12 every time we try to run it for 30 days worth of information.  This error message occurs directly after a connection is made to the RDS database.  I am still basically a beginner with most of this stuff so I was unsure if this "unhandled payload" was in relation to the lambda, or the rds, though I am leaning towards thinking it is related to the RDS.  I have never seen this error before and it seems to be a pretty broad error when researching it.

What could be the cause of this error if it is the RDS and how do I get around it?  Is it just that my database is too weak to handle the load?  The crazy thing is, even if I set a 60 second delay in between invocations of the next lambda, I still get this error.  But when I set the lambda on a 60 second trigger within the console and turn it on and off manually after 30 minutes, it runs perfectly.  I don't understand the difference between me setting a 60 second delay in my code to invoke a new instance of the lambda and setting a 60 second trigger through the console, when they both are firing off a new instance of the lambda every 60 seconds.  Why would one work perfectly and the other give me the error message above, when the only difference is one is invoked every 60 seconds through my code, the other is invoked every 60 seconds through the AWS Lambda console.

The goal is to have the lambda is triggered upon form submission of a webpage through an http endpoint in API-Gateway, carrying over a piece of info into the lambda from one of the forms.  The triggering from the api-gateway works, and the lambda works up to a point, so if I could have the endpoint enable the 60 second trigger, and turn it off after 1800 seconds or 30 minutes, i know for 100% fact it would function perfectly.  But its been bugging me that I can't understand why its not working when the ways of invoking the lambda are essentially doing the same thing, and that I can't find the cause of that error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure I have discovered the reason for the problem, and why a 60 second delay will never work for trying to recursively loop AWS-lambda functions.  From my best attempt to explain it, when you invoke a lambda programatically, by default, it is set to "synchronous mode".  Lets say you have 2 AWS-Lambda functions.  You invoke lambda 2 from lambda 1.  Lambda 1 will not consider itself finished until Lambda 2 is finished.  And if lambda 2 invokes a 3rd lambda, it it will start a chain doomed to fail.  On top of that, if an invoked lambda has not finished at the 2 minute mark, it will try to run it again, then 2 minutes later, a third time.

So the way I was running it, I was basically causing a chain reaction.  The further it got down the line, the longer the chain had built up, causing more and more lambdas to hit the 2 and 4 minute marks, causing the the same days entries to be uploaded multiple times in the database, flooding connections to the RDS and the API i was using, and eventually causing all lambdas to hit the 5 minute timeout.

The solution we found was to invoke it through an http endpoint through AWS API-Gateway.  It invokes the lambda and keeps going.  When we tried this, our countdown worked and 30 days of information was finished in minutes.

On another note, I know there is a way to set your programatically invoked lambda in "asynchronous mode." I have never used it, and I am unsure if it calls the function and keeps going, as I initially thought my original idea was doing, or if it waits the same just as synchronous mode does, i.e., the lambda it invokes has to finish before it considers itself finished.